# Combine/Cross Product of nested elements MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Is there a way to combine / produce a cross product of nested elements within MongoDB.
As an example I have

```
{
  images: 
  [
    {
        name: 'A',
        url: 'urlA'
    }, 
    {
        name: 'B',
        url: 'urlB'
    }
  ],
  tags: [
    {
        name: 'Tag1',
        description: 'description1'
    },
    {
        name: 'Tag2',
        description: 'description2'         
    }
  ]
}
```

By preferred result should be

```
[
    {
        url: 'urlA',
        name: 'Tag1'
    },
    {
        url: 'urlA',
        name: 'Tag2'
    },
    {
        url: 'urlB',
        name: 'Tag1'
    },
    {
        url: 'urlB',
        name: 'Tag2'
    }
]
```

Is it possible to store the generated documents in a new collection?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MongoDB Query

```
db.test.aggregate([
  { $unwind: '$images' },
  { $unwind: '$tags' },
  { "$group" : 
    { "_id" :
      { "url": "$images.url", "name": "$tags.name" }, 
    }
  },
  { "$group" :
    { "_id" : null, 
      "result": 
        { "$addToSet" : 
          { "url" : "$_id.url", "name" : "$_id.name" }
        },   
    }
  },
  {"$project": { "_id":0, "result": 1 }}
]);
```

**Output**

```
{
"result": [
    {
        "url": "urlA",
        "name": "Tag1"
    },
    {
        "url": "urlA",
        "name": "Tag2"
    },
    {
        "url": "urlB",
        "name": "Tag1"
    },
    {
        "url": "urlB",
        "name": "Tag2"
    }
]}
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution! I slightly modified it to my needs but the concept remains the same.